# WordPress 3.7.1, how to prevent Post Editor from cleaning up iframe class name?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to prevent the latest WordPress 3.7.1 from cleaning up embed codes that are being added from the "text tab" ?

I've got the following embed codes and similar that need to be added by users in the post editor:

```
<iframe class="vine-embed" src="https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT/embed/simple" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe><script async src="//platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

They get that from pages like this:

```
https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT/embed
```

This was working nicely, but after upgrading to WordPress 3.7.1, just after the user paste the Vine Embed Code in the "Text Tab", by switching to "Visual Editor tab" the class="vine-embed" is removed!

How can I prevent that from happening ?

I tried plugins like raw html plugin, but it didn't work.

Comment: I am not sure but please try to put that js before your <iframe> tag or best in header.php file

Answer (score 0):

WordPress editor is a pain... I'd solve this with a Shortcode:

```
[vineframe url="https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT/embed/simple"]
```

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Vine iFrame */

add_shortcode( 'vineframe', 'shortcode_so_19697294' );

function shortcode_so_19697294( $atts, $content )
{
    return sprintf(
        '<iframe class="vine-embed" src="%s" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe><script async src="//platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>',
        $atts['url']
    );
}
```